# Is it possible to be blacklisted by having various friendly "From" names in Emails?

Tags: .net, email, whitelist, blacklist

I have an invitation page where it's possible to send an email in order to invite other users to join the site.

But in order to seem more appealing to the recipients, I'd like to put the Email name as the name of the person who invited them.

Doing so is easy enough , but I'm just wondering if there's a chance to be blacklisted or categorized as spam by changing the From name in every single Email that gets sent out. The email will still be no-reply@client.com

I would also appreciate just hearing any comments about this, and if you think this is a cheap way to get more clicks or not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No.

But you will be blacklisted:

1. if more number of your recipients mark your mail as spam.
2. if the server finds more number of your mails are bounced back.
3. if your recipient mail-id is a spam-trap.
4. if you send bulk emails.
5. and this one is more important than the rest. if you send spam mails :)